# A bug about decorator in Python

Tags: python, decorator

The code is given as following:

```
import time
import sys

def LogClassFuncInfos(func):
    def wrapper(*s, **gs):
        methodName = format(func.__name__)
        print(methodName)
        func(*s, **gs)
    return wrapper

class NameModel():

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'test'

    @LogClassFuncInfos
    def getName(self):
        return self.name

a = NameModel()
print(a.getName())
```

The code is expected to print `'test'`, but the code prints `None`.

If the `@LogClassFuncInfos` before `def getName(self)` is removed, the `'test'` can be normally printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the result of `func(*s, **gs)` in `wrapper`.